# I need different fields in every stage of lead , do I need to create new module or what?

Tags: crm, odoo

Hi I need to develop CRM for my company. I choose OpenERP CRM module. It has stages and everything but I need that on every stage there must be some fields(some of them are required to move to next stage and some of them are optional) on leads page. Either I dont know the database structure or something else. So where to add fields (i mean in which object or table) One I was thinking to create a new module and use res_parter and user and create whole new CRM module. But then I was thinking that whats the benefit if I have to development. I am new in OpenERP , could not find my answer. Can somebody help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should customize the lead by extending it and adding the fields you need, then you can "play" with views for showing the fields, or making them required, as you like.

Also, if you say "So where to add fields (i mean in which object or table)" means that you didn't read the [developer docs](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/) :) Once you'll read them you'll find out that you don't need to know the tables in order to customize objects. After you read the docs, a good starting point is to have a look at other modules out there.

Have also a look at [this](http://simahawk.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/openerp-how-to-add-a-custom-field-to-an-object/).

Comment: thanks simhawk your quick response. I am newbie in openERP. I understand that I dont need to know the table , but objects. But the point is for different stages , if I add all fields in lead. How would I show them dynamically. for example lead.field1 and lead.field2 on stage1 and lead.field3 and lead.field4 on stage2. Second thing I want to show all changes in these fields as history. Sorry I extend my question . But I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: I can't give you a solution because I don't know your requirements. Depending on these you can probably store the information you need into a third object, but still, I cannot give you a solution. You have to 1st read the docs, then look at what ppl do in other modules, and if is not enough either you try to explain deeply what's your goal on the community mailing list (https://lists.launchpad.net/openerp-community/) or you contact a consultant.

Answer (score 0):

You have done good choice of OE for the CRM, their module CRM is really mature on this vertical. Now you have Some specific requirement that "(some of them are required to move to next stage and some of them are optional"  So I will Suggest few point here,

- Your few of last line "But then I was thinking that whats the benefit if I have to dvelopment." Yes You are completely light, Why todo it again, and OE also believe same. Here what you need is few hacks like fields_view_get, you need to create new small module which will inherit the `crm.lead` object and play with few code hack which will do job for you,
- Second Point is in CRM lead Stage is M2o relation field and they are linked with CRM Section that  is sales Team so this point, so this need more effort to integrate you requirement but yes developer point of view it is not much complex job at all.
- Why we need new module for feature reason is if you will create new module then in future if up upgrade your crm module with oe crm then you will not fill conflicts and your new module will like Plug able module ot OE. You can look in it apps.openerp.com for some existing modules, As they have more then 2k module, so it is quite possible you will get what you need.;) Or something similler

Hope This will help

Let me know if still has Doughts ,